# Create menu list vertically using li tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to create something similar to this using basic `li` tags. So, wanting to create a list that displays vertically and that pops over to the next row when the first row's is filled.

```
$row_max = 10;
echo '<ul>';
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo "<li class='vertical'>$item</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

With my css :

```
.vertical {
    float: left;
}
```

It's not doing what I want obviously, I don't know how to use my `$row_max` to tell it to move on to the next row after 10 elements on the first, being new I can't imagine how can I do the result I need... Any suggestions on which path to take? I don't specifically need an answer I understand you guys are busy, just on what to look for to answer my question.

[image: menu list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use the css `columns` ruleset ~ it is not dependant upon a height so if there are 20 or 200 `li` items it will grow accordingly beyond the `min-height`

```
    <style>
            ul{
                width:60%;
                min-height:200px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
                list-style:none;
                column-count: 4;
                column-width:25%;
                column-gap:1rem;
                column-rule: 1px solid gray;
                box-sizing:border-box;
            }
        </style>
```

To give an idea...

```
<?php
    echo "<ul>";
    for( $i=0; $i < 141; $i++ )echo "<li>List item $i</li>";/* any number...*/
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

[image: How it will look roughly]

to more closely resemble the image depicted in the question  there is a degree of randomness to the layout of list items. The actual layout would be controlled by the recordset and some logic in php but below is simply to emulate what it might look like.

```
<style>
        ul{
            font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
            width:60%;
            min-height:200px;
            float:none;
            margin:auto;
            list-style:none;
            column-count: 4;
            column-width:25%;
            column-gap:1rem;
            column-rule: 1px solid gray;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        h4{
            border-top:1px dotted gray;
            margin:0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
            padding:0.25rem 0 0 0;
            color:gray;
        }
    </style>

<?php

    $j=0;

    echo "<ul>";
    for( $i=0; $i < 100; $i++ ){


        echo "<li>List item $i</li>";

        if( $i > 0 && ( $i % rand(3,19) == 0 or $i % rand(12,23) == 0 ) ){
            $j++;
            echo "<h4>Category $j</h4>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";

?>
```

[image: randomised layout to indicate how it might look]

---

Had a little play around with javascript - made a little progress perhaps but have not fully solved the problem but perhaps the following might offer a little guidance ( perhaps not )

Some basic css

```
<style>
    ul{
        font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
        width:60%;
        min-height:50vh;
        max-height:100vh;
        height:auto;
        float:none;
        margin:auto;
        list-style:none;
        column-count: 4;
        column-width:25%;
        column-gap:1rem;
        column-rule: 1px solid gray;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    .breaker{
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:1.25rem;
        text-decoration:underline;
        border-top:1px dotted gray;
        padding:0.25rem 0 0 0;
        color:gray;
    }

    .breaker:first-of-type{
        border-top:1px solid transparent;
    }
    .breaker:last-of-type{
        border-bottom:2px solid dashed;
    }
</style>
```

A little PHP to emulate your menu system

```
<?php
    $j=0;
    $limit=rand(10,150);

    $html=array();
    $html[]="<ul id='menu'>";
    for( $i=0; $i < $limit; $i++ ){
        if( $i >= 0 && ( $i % rand(3,19) == 0 or $i % rand(12,23) == 0 ) ){
            $j++;
            $html[]="<li data-cat=$j class='breaker'>Category $j</li>";
        }
        $html[]="<li data-cat=$j>List item $i</li>";
    }
    $html[]="</ul>";
    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
?>
```

I tried using the `getBoundingClientRect()` method to determine if an element's left position had changed from a previous element. It more or less detects where the breaks should occur ( or one version did ) but it is the final act of generating the breaks which seems off. There are supposedly css tricks to force breaking when using the columns layout but support seems sketchy and I never had any success with anything I tried.....

```
<script>
    let cat,left=false;
    let tmp={};

    let i=j=0;
    let n=p=false;

    Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'ul#menu li.breaker' ) ).forEach( function( li, index ){
        if( index > 0 ){
            cat=parseInt( li.dataset.cat );
            left=parseInt( li.getBoundingClientRect().left );

            i=0;
            j=0;
            n = li.nextSibling;
            p = n.previousSibling;

            while( n && n.nodeType==1 && !n.classList.contains( 'breaker' ) ){
                if( parseInt( n.getBoundingClientRect().left ) > left ) i++;
                n = n.nextSibling;
                j++;
            };

            if( n && n.nodeType==1 && i > 0 && j > 0 ) tmp[cat]=j+1;
            return;
        }
    });


    const insertbreaks=function(i){
        let oFrag=document.createDocumentFragment();
        for( var a=0; a < i; a++ )oFrag.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
        return oFrag;
    };


    let keys=Object.keys( tmp );
    let vals=Object.values( tmp );

    for( i=keys.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ){
        let parent=document.querySelector('li[ data-cat=\"'+keys[ i ]+'\" ]');
        parent.parentNode.insertBefore( insertbreaks( vals[ i ] ), parent );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: One last question please before I mark this as answered. What if I want to tell `Category 3` to move to the next column as it doesn't fully fit inside the first column, how can I do that? (as that's a criteria in the image I posted in the OP)

Comment: I don't think that you can do that with a css only solution ~ at least not using the `columns` approach detailed above... if one were to use a different html structure with, for instance,  a new `ol` and subsequent `li` elements for each new category you could probably do so with css alone.

Comment: I don't mind if there is any js on the contrary I was thinking of a js solution, but how would I do so? How to detect that the third category has more elements than the height of it's specific column?

Comment: I understand if you don't have time to hint me, but please do say so as I'll be waiting for an answer if not so :)

Comment: I started to look at a javascript solution having further explored a pure css solution. I thought I had a pure css solution but it turns out support for some of the css is patchy across different browsers. I've been busy in the garage most of the day so the js is taking a back seat just now...

Comment: Thank you so much, please notify me when you've done it! :D [Here you can answer it in another question even](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169428/moving-li-to-next-column)

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox.

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 6em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for a defined height, but my height changes depending on the list of items in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could play about with flexbox to achieve this possibly if its based off the height rather than the number of results in each row.

```
ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   height: 100px;
}
```

If you are doing it based off the max rows I would suggest counting the lis in the loop and if the result is a multiple of row_max and a new ul with the next 10 results.

Comment: It's unfortunately based on the number of results in each row :)

Comment: Would you please be kind enough to share an example of what the CSS would look like in this case?

Comment: I dont really know php but if you can split the uls based on the count, i.e 0 starts ul and 10 closes ul and reset until your loop is over. It should be as simple as this https://jsfiddle.net/fsjwxad8/2/

Comment: I meant the CSS not the PHP, would it still look like the example you gave above?

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong link. It should look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/fsjwxad8/2/. You can add as many uls as you want and it should sort each into a row