# Moving li to next column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a simple `ul` like so :

```css
ul.target {
  font-family: calibri, verdana, arial;
  min-height: 500px;
  float: none;
  column-count: 4;
  column-width: 25%;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  column-rule: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li > ul { 
  break-after: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<ul class="target">
  <li class="categ">category 1</li>
  <li class="item">test 1</li>
  <li class="item">test 2</li>
  <li class="categ">category 2</li>
  <li class="item">test 3</li>
  <li class="item">test 4</li>
  <li class="item">test 5</li>
  <li class="item">test 6</li>
  <li class="item">test 7</li>
  <li class="item">test 8</li>
  <li class="categ">category 3</li>
  <li class="item">test 9</li>
  <li class="item">test 10</li>
  <li class="item">test 11</li>
  <li class="item">test 12</li>
  <li class="item">test 13</li>
  <li class="item">test 14</li>
  <li class="item">test 15</li>
  <li class="item">test 16</li>
  <li class="item">test 17</li>
  <li class="item">test 18</li>
  <li class="categ">category 4</li>
  <li class="item">test 19</li>
  <li class="item">test 20</li>
  <li class="item">test 21</li>
  <li class="item">test 22</li>
  <li class="item">test 23</li>
  <li class="item">test 24</li>
  <li class="categ">category 5</li>
  <li class="item">test 25</li>
  <li class="item">test 26</li>
  <li class="item">test 27</li>
  <li class="item">test 28</li>
  <li class="item">test 29</li>
  <li class="item">test 30</li>
  <li class="item">test 31</li>
  <li class="item">test 32</li>
  <li class="item">test 33</li>
</ul>
```

As you can [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/tef061xd/31/), category 2 is at the very bottom and category 3 is in the middle. I want to be able to move them to the next column dynamically if they're at the very bottom. Knowing that the height might be larger and there could be a lot of other categories in each column, I want to push the LAST category of the column to the next column, thus modifying the rest of the columns accordingly. I don't have any idea on where to start...

EDIT, taken from comments :

To clarify somet hings : 
My code is a small example of a larger code containing much more than that, so no the question is still about how can I move each category to the next column, trying to find another way of doing it won't work in my case as this is just a preview. I'm using JQuery in order to get the categories and the list of items, and then I don't know what to do to push the category to the next column using JS. It should just reposition to the next column if it's the last category of the current column.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @BenM thank you for your comment! As I've said, I don't know where to start or what logic is adapted here. I'm not looking for a pure answer, just an idea on where would I start resolving the problem myself.

Comment: Your problem is described here> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082368/css-columns-target-last-child-in-each-column Basically, how to target last child in column, and how to replace/move it, if it is .categ li. I would rather change html structure (dynamically created, as i can see) at the very start....

Comment: You might take a look at [Insert column break in css3 column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43814097) as it appears to be what you're looking for; be sure to read the whole answer, as it has a collapsed snippet which might be what you want.

Comment: @sinisake you would change the structure to what?

Comment: @Elshobokshy, well, if you need category at the top, solve it before creating html output?

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question after you've received answers. You've basically taken the code from my answer and made it the question, which isn't fair, and makes it look like I copied your code. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Feel free to link back to this one, but make sure the new question stands on its own.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm sorry, you're totally right, I marked your answer as answered to thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the `break-before` property to the `.categ` class, but then you end up with three columns:

```js
var item = $(".item")
var categ = $(".categ")
```

```css
ul {
  font-family: calibri, verdana, arial;
  min-height: 500px;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 4;
  column-width: 25%;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  column-rule: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.categ {
  break-before: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="categ">category 1</li>
  <li class="item">test 1</li>
  <li class="item">test 2</li>
  <li class="categ">category 2</li>
  <li class="item">test 3</li>
  <li class="item">test 4</li>
  <li class="item">test 5</li>
  <li class="item">test 6</li>
  <li class="item">test 7</li>
  <li class="item">test 8</li>
  <li class="categ">category 3</li>
  <li class="item">test 9</li>
  <li class="item">test 10</li>
  <li class="item">test 11</li>
  <li class="item">test 12</li>
</ul>
```

You have to alter the DOM in order to get this to work. In the following snippet I've made "sublists" out of the `.categ` list items and all their following `.item` siblings (using jQuery as you'd included it in your snippet). I've also added a class to the top-most `ul` so as to differentiate it for styling. You could also use a class on the `ul`s for the "sublists" instead of using the child selector as I did.

```js
$(".categ").each((idx, cat) => $(cat).nextUntil(".categ", ".item").addBack().wrapAll("<li><ul>"));
```

```css
ul.target {
  font-family: calibri, verdana, arial;
  min-height: 500px;
  float: none;
  column-count: 4;
  column-width: 25%;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  column-rule: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li > ul { 
  break-after: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<ul class="target">
  <li class="categ">category 1</li>
  <li class="item">test 1</li>
  <li class="item">test 2</li>
  <li class="categ">category 2</li>
  <li class="item">test 3</li>
  <li class="item">test 4</li>
  <li class="item">test 5</li>
  <li class="item">test 6</li>
  <li class="item">test 7</li>
  <li class="item">test 8</li>
  <li class="categ">category 3</li>
  <li class="item">test 9</li>
  <li class="item">test 10</li>
  <li class="item">test 11</li>
  <li class="item">test 12</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain your code? As it ends up making [5 columns](https://jsfiddle.net/tef061xd/29/), I feel that it's making a column for every category, and not the last category of the column.

Comment: Your first code does the same thing, the `break-columns` on `categ` puts every `categ` in a new column and not the last categ.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, the first one was just a demonstration of the fact that `break-before` doesn't work like you want. Your fiddle there has different HTML than the sample you gave. With the code you presented in your original question, it works. No fair moving the goalposts...

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer, I'm a little unsure about what you're trying to do:**

I think the problem is not the presentation rules (CSS) you apply to your data (HTML). I think the problem is dat your data does not provide enough context for you presentation rules to act upon.

What I think you're trying to do is to have 3 (or more) separate lists presented on something that looks like a footer. However your HTML structures does not seem to properly match this scheme.

Try to make your HTML more explicit. Why put everything in one list instead of one list per category? Then you could justify the categories the way you want by either floats or flex or even grid layouts. I don't see why you should need jQuery for this?

Or have I misinterpreted your question?

Comment: My code is a small example of a larger code containing much more than that, so no the question is still about how can I move each category to the next column, trying to find another way of doing it won't work in my case as this is just a preview. I'm using JQuery in order to get the categories and the list of items, and then I don't know what to do to push the category to the next column using JS. What are you unsure about?

Comment: I'm unsure about what you mean with "move". Do you want to be able to drag and drop items from one column to the other. Or do you expect a certain content "flow".

Comment: No, not drag and drop, it should just reposition to the next column if it's the last category of the current column. I'm sorry if my terms are not the right ones! So yes, a certain content flow.

Comment: I've illustrated my example: https://codepen.io/svenvandescheur/pen/xarqxv. This example relies on: A: grouped categories in HTML, B: a known max height for the container. C: Flex layout.

Comment: I've upvoted, but unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for still, as my page heavily relies on the CSS I have on my OP and I can not change it easily, the page needs to contain `column-count`. I also can't change the format of my HTML. So the answer really needs to use the code I've written above.

Comment: What possibilities do you have to alter CSS? If you have no room to change code you have no room to change product. Does your OP allow some sort of overwriting stylesheets?

Comment: This is does not appear to be an answer, but rather a series of questions trying to clarify the question. That purpose is served by comments here on Stack Overflow. If you have an answer, please include the code in the answer itself, rather than only on an external site.

Comment: @Elshobokshy It would be good to edit your question to include any clarifications or requirements you've made in comments here.